# Pandas read_csv big file puts every column into one

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a [csv file](https://files.fm/u/7rgp8dkx) and I'm trying to read it via pandas command read_csv. However instead of reading 5 rows and 21 columns I get the following output: 
[image]

There is a possible solution of manually changing the bad formatting of the file however, the real size is quite big(around 1GB) and it isnt possible to change it manually.

Comment: Try defining the delimiter as a comma.

Comment: there may be problem with csv file.

Comment: @DylanSmith I tried it sir. No luck unfortunately :(

Comment: try opening file with libreoffice in that you can define delemeter before opening it. find correct delemeter then use in python.

Comment: Could you just paste the first line of your csv file?

Comment: replace all your ` "" ` in csv with single double quotes `"`

Comment: he has given link of csv @SembeiNorimaki

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I didnt quite understand what you wrote sir. Paste the first row where? Paste it as a header?

Comment: @VanPeer That might be a solution but I'm dealing with a great amount of files here (around 1Gb) and you can easily guess that's not possible to happen sir.

Comment: @GeorgeDavidKing ok, how about `sep="\"\,\""`, and you can change the type of the columns in the resulting df

Comment: @VanPeer Sir we are almost there! However with this sep its reading (5, 20) instead of (5,21) putting the first two columns together.

Comment: @GeorgeDavidKing you can split those using `,` as the separator right. now that we're here, time to look for a regex separator, probably!

Comment: @VanPeer Can you please elaborate the whole , separator right thing?

Comment: @GeorgeDavidKing you can give column `split` a try. I was checking to use a regular expression as the separator, but those are prone to ignoring quoted data it seems.

Comment: @VanPeer's comment answers it all. Your csv file is uneven. Everything is wrapped inside double `"` (`""element""`) except for first column header, which is broken. `"c_id`. You might have to reformat your csv or once you read it in a dataframe, then split columns.

Comment: `df.iloc[:,0].str.split(',', expand=True)` would give you the right result. You might have to append that back to your df.

Comment: @HarvIpan something like this : df=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\student\Desktop\test.csv',sep="\"\,\"",engine='python',iloc[:,0].str.split(',', expand=True)) pops a SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

Comment: Consider my answer. Let me know, if it does not work.

Comment: @HarvIpan It did. Thank you again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below solution:

```
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", sep="\"\,\"")
data = pd.concat([df.iloc[:,0].str.split(',', expand=True).rename(columns=dict(zip([0,1], df.columns[0].split(',')))), df.iloc[:,1:]], axis=1)
```

Would return a `(5,21)` shape of `data`.